# склонение слова "средство"

Tags: склонение

Пишу дипломную работу, мой руководитель сформулировала тему: «Методические пути использования изобразительной наглядности на уроках истории в 6 классе как средствА достижения личностных результатов обучения». На кафедре считают, что правильнее здесь звучит формулировка темы, когда слово «средство» стоит в именительном падеже,т.е, вот так: «Методические пути использования изобразительной наглядности на уроках истории в 6-ом классе как средствО достижения личностных результатов обучения». Аналогичный вопрос возникает при формулировке глав и пунктов в дипломе: «Теоретические основы использования изобразительной наглядности в обучении истории в основной школе как средствО (или средствА) достижения личностных…», «Анализ практики использования исторических картин на уроках истории в 6 классе как средствО (или средствА) достижения личностных результатов обучения», «Методические рекомендации по использованию исторических картин в 6 классе как средствО (или средствА) достижения личностных результатов обучения». Скажите, как верно? Буду Вам очень признательна за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) *Методические пути использования **изобразительной наглядности** на уроках истории в 6 классе **как средства** достижения личностных результатов обучения.*

Есть **два возможных варианта:**

(1) методические **пути** (И.п.)  **как средство** (И.п.);

(2) изобразительной **наглядности** (Р.п.)  **как средства** (в качестве средства, Р.п.).

Вряд ли ***методические пути*** следует считать средством, средством является именно  ***изобразительная наглядность***.

2) Но тогда может быть  такое прочтение: методические пути (И.п.) как средства (И.п.), а это надо **исключить**.

Предлагаемый вариант:

*Методика использования **изобразительной наглядности** **как средства** улучшения личностных результатов обучения на уроках истории в 6 классе.*

3) А еще лучше так:

*Методика использования **изобразительной наглядности** для улучшения личностных результатов обучения на уроках истории в 6 классе.*

Нет ***средства*** — нет проблем.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос заключается не столько в строгом склонении слова по падежам, а в том смысле, который это склонение несёт. В данном случае обе формы: „средств**о**” и „средств**а**” — могут быть употреблены. Сам нашёл три различных случая, в каждом из которых данное слово имеет индивидуальное значение:

1. Если мы говорим о том, что **использование изобразительной наглядности** есть средство для достижения какой-либо цели, то необходимо использовать падеж, согласующийся с данным сочетанием, то есть родительный.
2. Если же мы относим по смыслу слово, являющееся предметом спора, к сочетанию „методические пути”, то получаем следующую взаимосвязь:

Методические пути есть соседство.

Соответственно, здесь необходим именительный падеж. Но, обязательно надо отметить, вариант с окончанием -а здесь также уместен на основании **множественного числа**. То есть теперь взаимосвязь следующая:

Методические пути есть средства.

Разница лишь в том, подразумеваем мы, что методические пути это **единое** средство достижения цели либо комплекс мероприятий, направленных, опять-таки, на достижение определённого результата.

Если возникли вопросы, оставьте их в комментариях к собственному вопросу.

Answer (score 0):

Хотел ограничится комментарием, но поскольку ответ уже "забит", даю своё понимание.

Ваш вопрос - это стилистика, грамматика позволяет оба варианта. Но у вариантов несколько разное значение (или акцент как минимум). Вы подумайте, что точнее по смыслу. ***"Использование как средства"*** или ***"пути как средство"***. Мне первый вариант ближе.

Так что я бы оставил вариант руководителя ***«Методические пути использования изобразительной наглядности на уроках истории в 6 классе как средствА достижения личностных результатов обучения»***. Но как это на кафедре объяснить - не берусь советовать...